# List directories up to the level of my files only

Tags: r, path, directory

This line gives me hierarchical directory paths down to the files:

```
dirs<- as.data.frame(list.dirs(path = rootdir, full.names = F, recursive = T))
```

Like so:

```
"","list.dirs(path = rootdir, full.names = F, recursive = T)"
"1",""
"2","19"
"3","19/H"
"4","19/H/BA"
"5","19/H/BA/2016"
"6","19/H/BA/2016/11"
"7","19/H/BA/2016/11/10"
"8","19/H/BA/2016/11/10/0" # files are in here
"9","19/H/BA/2016/12"
"10","19/H/BA/2016/12/20"
"11","19/H/BA/2016/12/20/0" # files are in here
"12","19/H/BA/2017"
"13","19/H/BA/2017/1"
"14","19/H/BA/2017/1/19"
"15","19/H/BA/2017/1/19/0" # files are in here
"16","19/H/BA/2017/1/29"
"17","19/H/BA/2017/1/29/0" # files are in here
"18","19/H/BA/2017/3"
"19","19/H/BA/2017/3/20"
"20","19/H/BA/2017/3/20/0" # files are in here
```

But how would I write the code to only give me the paths to the files? I.e.,

```
"19/H/BA/2016/11/10/0"
"19/H/BA/2016/12/20/0"
"19/H/BA/2017/1/19/0"
"19/H/BA/2017/1/29/0"
"19/H/BA/2017/3/20/0"
```

Comment: Do you need only path of the folders which consists of any files? Are rest of the folders empty?

Comment: @RonakShah: yes the rest of the folders are empty of files.

Comment: `list.files` returns the path of only those files which exist but I think you need the path to be one level up?

Comment: @RonakShah: Yes - I would need one level up to avoid duplication of paths to the same folder....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `list.files` to get the path of all the files which are present (so that it doesn't give us any empty directory paths).

```
filepath = list.files(rootdir, recursive = T)
```

Now this will have path to all the files, we can use `sub` to remove the filenames from it and keep only the directory name.

```
sub("[/].*", "", filepath)
```

This removes everything from `/`. Finally to avoid duplication we can take `unique` of it.

To do everything in one liner.

```
unique(sub("[/].*", "", list.files(rootdir, recursive = T)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dirname` instead of a regular expression, this will handle special cases like `rootdir == "C:/"` or `rootdir == "../"` :

```
unique(dirname(list.files(rootdir,rec=T)))
```